# How to restrict windows logon for some time?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, productivity

I have written powershell script which locks Windows-10 machine after an hour.
This script is written to take a break from work. Scripts works fine it locks the machine. But after lock I can logon to machine without taking a break from work. How can I restrict windows login for next 10 minutes using powershell so machine can not be used(So I have to take a break forcefully) ?

Answer (score 0):

Putting this here since it is too long for the comment section.

This is not a PowerShell issue, problem. It is a Windows Local or Group Policy one.

So, are you asking how to use PowerShell to set a policy vs using the GUI? You could have avoided using PowerShell at all and use policy and that is a long time well-documented thing.

For example:

https://blog.encyro.com/how-to-force-windows-10-to-lock-itself-after-inactivity-for-all-users

To close to what you are after, you are going to have to code this, and this means employing the Task Scheduler in the mix as well. Meaning on your lock effort you need to set a file or a regkey to store the lock time, and when you logon, set a script to fire off that check the timestamp in the file or regkey, and if less than 10 from the lock time, relock the system.

Comment: Want to restrict keyboard entries in windows login input box for 10 min. So that forcefully I must take a break.

Comment: Create two Tasks with triggers set to **On Workstation Lock**, first one should start immidiaetly and set the group policy named **"Deny log on locally** for all/desired user accounts to true, and second Task should have a delay of 10 mins and revert **Deny log on locally* GP to it's default setting. Although I don't see why are you bothering with this, just take a break it's not heroin.